# Fixed-элемент после зума выходит за границы экрана, нет возможности увидеть оставшееся.

Tags: вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте. Так и не смог сформулировать краткий и понятный заголовок.
Ситуация:
на сайте написан лайтбокс, у которого позиционирование фиксированное.
Внутри вылазит, например, изображение. После приближения зумом (хоть на десктопе, хоть на мобильном приложении) элемент, естественно, выходит за границы экрана, однако при попытке "прокрутить вправо", чтобы увидеть оставшуюся часть элемента, прокручивается лишь основной контент сайта, а фиксированный элемент остаётся на месте (что логично).

Вопрос:
Как сделать, чтобы была возможность прокрутки этого самого fixed-элемента, чтобы можно было увидеть целиком его содержимое после зума?

в гугле ничего не смог найти, даже не знаю, как корректно сформулировать запрос к нему.

Answer (score 1):

Если для вашего сайта нет мобильной версии, то могу посоветовать лишь огранить размер вашего fixed-блока по максимальной высоте экрана, а внутри враппера сделать скролл, чтобы можно было увидеть контент. Так как не вижу вашего кода, оставляю лишь грубый пример:

```
.fixed {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```